# Unable to suppress echo with ROC in RMarkdown

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, roc

I am not able to suppress the echo of roc command (pROC package) despite setting echo to FALSE in the code chunk.  the roc commands outputs "call" and "data" lines to the pdf.  Can anyone help me figure out how to turn it off?

````
---
title: "ROC echo"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r,echo=F,warning=F,message=F, comment=NA, results='asis',fig.width=10}
library(pROC)
data(iris)
iris$setosa <- ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa","setosa","not setosa") 
iris.roc <- roc(setosa ~ Sepal.Width,data =iris)
plot.roc(iris.roc)
```
````

[image]

Comment: How about `invisible(plot.roc(iris.roc))`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer `plot.roc` already returns its first argument invisibly.

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: Martin, your suggestion worked and the extra output lines are gone now.  BTW, I am running in OSX.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `echo` only effects the printing of the source code according to [knitr documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/), not the output of R commands:

> `echo`: (TRUE; logical or numeric) whether to include R source code in
>   the output file;

What you really want is `results='hide'` instead of `'asis'`:

> `results`: ('markup'; character) takes these possible values
>
> - (...)
> - `asis`: output as-is, i.e., write raw results from R into the output document
> - (...)
> - `hide` hide results; this option only applies to normal R output (not warnings, messages or errors)

Comment: @Calmino, thank you for the answer. setting `results="hide"` did work as expected.